# Google drive shared with non Google account

Tags: google-drive

I've had a Google drive file shared with a non Google email account (that I traditionally access via outlook).  When I click the link, my browser (which is logged in to my google account) tells me that I need permission.

I try signing out of that Google account in my browser, and following the link again, but just get asked to sign in.  Of course, I can't with the relevant account as it's not a Google account..

I've now tried adding the non-google email as an 'associated email' to my Google account, but I still get told that I need permission.

Any suggestions how to access this file?  Unfortunately getting it re-sent to my Google account is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Google account with the non-Google email address, which you can then use to sign in to your Drive.

Comment: I've tried that now too, and unfortunately it *still* says I need permission.

Comment: Are you able to log in with the original google account and share it again? (you should be able to add the non - Google address to the share (if not take the old one off first)

Comment: The file was shared with me, so I can't alter the share settings.

Comment: Are you able to copy the file or do you need to keep the original there? If the latter, you probably will have to ask the owner to reshare it.

Comment: yeah looking like that's the only option.  just very strange that google would allow the link to be shared, but then forbid access using all these different approaches.

Comment: Yes, that is odd. The original email address would have been permitted to access the file, and I can't think of a reason why that should have changed.